creating card slider sliding individual card by clicking specific button previous or next using javascript
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>my slider</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../pages/images/favicon.ico">

    <!-- stylesheet  -->
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .card-container {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 2.5px solid #000000;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }

        .card-slider {
            display: flex;
            border: 1.5px solid #ff0000;
        }
        
        .card {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .prev, .next {
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -285px;
        }

        .next {
            right: 0px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card-slider">
            <div class="card" style="background-color: #0ffff0;">Card One</div>
            <div class="card" style="background-color: #cab;">Card Two</div>
            <div class="card" style="background-color: #12abc2;">Card Three</div>
            <div class="card" style="background-color: #9000bc;">Card Four</div>
            <div class="card" style="background-color: #500bc1;">Card Five</div>
            <div class="card" style="background-color: #acb111;">Card Six</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="prev" onclick="previousSlide()">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="next" onclick="nextSlide()">&#10095;</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let currentCard = 0;
        let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
        let totalCards = cards.length;

        
        function showCard() {
            cards[currentCard].style.transform = `translateX(${-100}%)`; // trying to move this card left
            /* only first click above statement execute correctly and move card left 
            but also other click above statement execute but not as I expect
            on second, third etc click above statement move card right direction instead of left direction
            I got the correct logic for above statement to excecute correct way to move card in left direction
            I modify the above statement from this  cards[currentCard].style.transform = `translateX(${-100}%)`;
            to this cards[currentCard].style.transform = `translateX(${-100 * (currentCard + 1)}%)`;
            but I want explanation why cards[currentCard].style.transform = `translateX(${-100}%)`; statement
            move cards to right direction not for first click but second, third etc clicks. */


                // after moving above card space created between currentCard and currentCard +1

                // this for loop for  remove space between the cards
                for(let i = currentCard + 1; i < totalCards; i++ ) {
                // cards[i].style.transform = `translateX(${-100}%)`;
                // cards[i].style.transform = `translateX(${-100 * (currentCard + 1) }%)`;
                cards[i].style.transform = `translateX(calc(${-100 * (currentCard + 1)}% + ${(currentCard + 1) * -20}px ))`;
                console.log("Value of i: ", i, " currentCard: ", currentCard);
            }
            // after come out from for loop slide currentCard end of the all other cards
            cards[currentCard].style.transform = `translateX(${100 * totalCards}%)`;

            // increment currentCard
            currentCard++;
        }
        
        function nextSlide () {
            showCard();
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>

I'm trying to creat a card slider to slide individual cards
my logic:
function show card() {...}
first statement of this function is slide current card by left -100%
after sliding current card space crated between currentCard and currentCard +1
to remove space creating one for loop to slide cards left -100% one by one
after coming out from for loop move current card end of the last card
increment currentCard;
function nextSlide() {...}
show current card
but first statement of showCard(){...} function and for loop run only once.
why?? what's wrong in my code please answer my question or help me to provide a better solution or explain my code step by step please...

hello it, goldman please tell me the problem in my code why first statement or for loop run only once please help me in my code or explain my code.

Your code has logical problem. The transform must increase after sliding, you can use your currentCard variable for that.
Solution
for ( let i = currentCard +1; i < totalCards; i++ ) {
   cards[i].style.transform = `translateX(${-100 * (currentCard + 1) }%)`; // Check this line
   console.log("Value of i: ",i, " currentCard: ",currentCard);
} 

And now you should include the gap (the margin size) between cards, I will use calc css method to sum percentage (%) with px, here is the code:
for ( let i = currentCard +1; i < totalCards; i++ ) {
   cards[i].style.transform = `translateX(calc(${-100 * (currentCard + 1)}% + ${(currentCard+1) * -20}px ))`; // Add -20px for the cards margin
   console.log("Value of i: ",i, " currentCard: ",currentCard);
} 

It is working perfectly now.

Edit:
More Explanation
When you press the next button, the for loop will shift every card by -100%, when you click it again, the cards will not be shifted anymore, because the translateX is still the same as the first click -100%.
So the logic here is to increase the translateX by -100% every click, like: -100% > -200% > -300% > ...
In your showCard function, the currentCard is incremented by 1 for each execution (of course the function is executed when button is clicked).
Now, we can use this variable to apply our logic:
cards[i].style.transform = `translateX(${-100 * (currentCard + 1) }%)`;

The currentCard initial value is 0, and -100 * 0 is equal to 0, but we need it to be -100 on the first execution, so we need to add 1 to it. -100 * 1 = -100
And it will work, now to get rid of the white space caused created by margin-right: 20px for each card, we will apply the same logic but with -20 instead of -100, and combine the two operations using css calc method.
cards[i].style.transform = `translateX(calc(${-100 * (currentCard + 1)}% + ${(currentCard + 1) * -20}px ))`;

The value of translateX (with calc method) will be (in click sequence):
-100% - 20px > -200% - 40px > -300% - 60px > ...

thanks brother for giving solution now it's working as I want. please explain why this cards[currentCard].style.transform = translateX(${-100}%); did'nt work this shift card to right but i'm using transform = translateX(${-100}%); please tell me the reason.

@Mohanmohan I will edit my answer for more explanation.

ok I'm waiting for your explanation brother.

hello brother I edit code please review my showCard() {...} first statement of the function and explain what is happening please read comment block comment, block comment describe my problem.

@Mohanmohan After reading your edit, I became a little confused about your goal, is your goal to move the cards to the left instead of the right? Another thing... I prefer to ask (create) new question to be more focus in your current issue, thank you.

Here is the full infinite scroll you were trying to build. Run the snippet to see it in action.->
The problem with your code is, you are assuming that, by applying translateX(${-100}%) multiple times, the cards will change their position by the sum of the values. That's wrong. Applying translateX(${-100}%) twice, won't move the cards by -200. You have to specify the exact values, because you are assigning a new position to the cards by using =. No matter how many times you apply translateX(${-100}%), the cards will always remain at -100. So the solution is to apply different percentage of move to different card. For example to move the cards to left, the first card should be moved by -100%, the second should be moved by -200%, the third should be moved by -300% and so on. Or to move them to the right, apply 100% to the first card, 200% to the second card and like that.


let currentCard = 0;
let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
let totalCards = cards.length;

function showCard() {

  for (let i = 0; i < totalCards; i++) {
    cards[i].style.transform = `translateX(${-100 * (currentCard + 1) }%)`;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= currentCard; i++) {
    cards[i].style.transform = `translateX(${500 -(100*currentCard) }%)`;
  }

  (currentCard <= 4) ? currentCard++ : currentCard = 0;
}

function nextSlide() {
  showCard();
}

function previousSlide() {
  //
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-container {
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2.5px solid #000000;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.card-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 200px;
  flex-basis: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.card img {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.prev,
.next {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.next {
  right: 0px;
}
<body>
  <div class="card-container">
    <button class="prev" onclick="previousSlide()">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="next" onclick="nextSlide()">&#10095;</button>
    <div class="card-slider">
      <div class="card">
        <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/BMW_logo_%28gray%29.svg' /> </div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: #cab;">Card Two</div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: #12abc2;">Card Three</div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: #9000bc;">Card Four</div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a1/Larsen%26Toubro_logo.svg' />
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: #acb111;">Card Six</div>
    </div>
  </div>




hello brother please tell me why this statement
shifts cards to right direction instead of left direction cards[currentCard].style.transform = translateX(${-100}%); // trying to move this card left

@Mohanmohan It shouldn't. Are you talking about my code? Or are you trying something else?

hello brother I'm talking about my code in function showCard(){…} in my question please review my question in script tag showCard(){…} first statement this move card right direction instead of left direction. please review my showCard() {…} and tell me what's wrong in that statement. I'm waiting your response

@Mohanmohan The currentCard is moving right because of translateX(${100 * totalCards }%). First you are moving it to left by setting the translate to -100px, then you moving it to right by 600px using the third statement. So to sum up, you are setting the card right to '500px'. If you really want to see what is happening, Open Developer tools of your browser and go to elements and check the cards and how the value of translate() changes when we click the next button.

hello brother I edit code please review my showCard() {...} first statement of the function and explain what is happening please read comment block comment, block comment describe my problem.

@Mohanmohan You aren't getting it. We are using template literals here because we cannot manipulate translate() directly. Template literals replace the current value of the transform, it cannot alter the existing value. That's why it isn't working as expected. Read my answer carefully, it already explains why it is working the way it is.
